# Create hidden or unchangeable parameter to my API in Swagger-UI?

Tags: javascript, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

I need to either:

A) Create a hidden parameter that is passed with every call generated from my Swagger-UI interface to my API (i.e. ?test=true)

OR

B) Expose the 'test' parameter in the UI but set it to true by default and NOT allow a change to this.

How can either of these be accomplished from within Swagger-UI ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? It seems backwards. Any parameters need to be controlled in the API, not in swagger. Once I have access to your API I can just submit things outside of swagger anyway.

Comment: @DigitalChris fully agree. The API writes data to a table in Mongo and I want to be able to easily weed out the 'test' requests generated by the Swagger UI vs. the real requests coming from apps. That's the purpose behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forced UI to have "test" as true using enum and required true;
Only forced if type integer or string. Boolean will auto-list true and false to the dropdown

YAML :

```
  parameters:
    - name: test
      description: Test environment
      required: true
      type: string
      in: query
      enum:
        - True
```

Json:

```
 "name":"test",
 "description": "Test environment",
 "required": true,
 "type":"string",
 "in":"query",
 "enum":["true"]
```